# flutter web webview How do I know if the page has changed?

Tags: flutter

I receive payments via webview on the mobile side of flutter web and I understand whether it is successful or not based on the returned url, but flutter does not seem to support this on the web side of webview, how can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect when webview url changes in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65155047/how-to-detect-when-webview-url-changes-in-flutter)

Comment: Unfortunately, webview does not support these features on the web side.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter webview is very insufficient on the web side, so I communicated with the code in the hosting according to the url returned successfully or unsuccessfully via iframe.

```
class Secure3D extends StatefulWidget {
  final String content;
  final Function(String url) whenPaymentComplete;

  Secure3D({required this.content, required this.whenPaymentComplete, Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _Secure3DState createState() => _Secure3DState();
}

class _Secure3DState extends State<Secure3D> {
  late html.IFrameElement _iframeElement;

  @override
  void initState() {
    final htmlCode = widget.content;

    _iframeElement = html.IFrameElement()
      ..srcdoc = htmlCode
      ..style.border = 'none';

    // ignore:undefined_prefixed_name
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      'iframeElement',
      (int viewId) => _iframeElement,
    );
    html.window.onMessage.listen((event) {
      var message = event.data;
      widget.whenPaymentComplete(message);
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Center(
            child: HtmlElementView(
              viewType: 'iframeElement',
              key: UniqueKey(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```